# Angular 2 & django integration

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, angular

I'm a newbie to Angular2 and I'm having some difficulties to integrate my Angular2 app with my django app.

I already have REST api all set-up and consumed by the Angular app. I just want to use django urls to load my angular app through index.html file with SystemJS.

The problem is that I'm getting 404 errors when angular tries to load files and I think it's because it tries to load via absolute path and not by a relative one.

Is my approach OK? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

**Edit:** some extra info,

- STATIC_ROOT & STATIC_PATH are set to '/static/'
- index.html is in 'templates' directory
- all angular 2 files are in 'static/angular2' directory

**index.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="SYSTEM">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="{% static 'angular2/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'angular2/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'angular2/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'angular2/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js' %}"></script>


    <!-- Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="{% static 'angular2/systemjs.config.js' %}"></script>
    <script>
      System.import("{% static 'angular2/app/main.js' %}").catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>

    <!-- js -->
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Page styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,bold,italic,thin,light,bolditalic,black,medium&amp;lang=en">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.purple-blue.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'angular2/css/styles.css' %}">

  </head>
  <body>
    <app>
      loading...
    </app>
  </body>
</html>
```

**systemjs.config.js**

```
(function(global) {
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'ng2-tag-input':              'node_modules/ng2-tag-input',
    'ng2-charts':                 'node_modules/ng2-charts',
    'ng2-datetime-picker':        'node_modules/ng2-datetime-picker',
    'ng2-draggable':              'node_modules/ng2-draggable',
    'angular2-infinite-scroll':   'node_modules/angular2-infinite-scroll'
  };

  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'ng2-tag-input':              { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'ng2-charts':                 { main: 'ng2-charts.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'ng2-datetime-picker':        { main: 'dist/index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'ng2-draggable':              { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-infinite-scroll':   { main: 'angular2-infinite-scroll.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };

  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];

  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }

  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }

  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;

  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyDiV.png)

Comment: Include the relevant code so we could see what's wrong. As for what's relevant - [this Help Center article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should help.

Comment: Make sure your angular2 files (html/css/js) are all added to to the TEMPLATES and STATIC directives in django's settings

Comment: @rafalmp Hey I added some code and information, thanks!